# Selecting only a subset of columns in linked entity in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Please don't ask me **why** I need to do this, as even if I think I could find another way to solve my specific problem, I want to understand HQL and its limits more.

Given the following entities

```
@Entity
class Child {

    private String someAttribute1;
    .....
    private String someAttributeN;

    @ManyToOne(EAGER)
    private Parent parent;

}

class Parent {

    private String someParent1;
    ....
    private String someParentN;
}
```

If I `select Child` then Hibernate automatically fetches all columns from `Child` and `Parent` in a single joined SQL, and that is the typical desired case.

Sometimes I know that, for entities mapped with a large number of columns, I need only a subset.

If I `select item.someAttribute1 as someAttribute1, item.someAttribute2 as someAttribute2, item.someAttribute3 as someAttribute3 from Child item` etc. tied to a `ResultTransformer` I can let Hibernate return me only 3 columns from the SQL, or more columns if I list them. OK, that is cool and works like a charm.

However if I need to fetch only, say, 3 columns from `Child` and 2 from `Parent`, while the rest can be null, and materialize a `Child` entity with its relationship, **I cannot** write the following

```
select item.someAttribute1 as someAttribute1, item.someAttribute2 as someAttribute2, item.someAttribute3 as someAttribute3, item.parent.someParent1 as parent.someParent1, item.parent.someParent2 as parent.someParent2 from Child item left join item.parent
```

The above does not work because Hibernate does not allow an alias to be composed. It disallows me to use `as parent.someName` clause because aliases should probably be flat.

Just to tell a counter example, in languages such as LINQ the problem does not apply

```
from Child c in children
select new Child {
    SomeAttribute1 = c.someAttribute1,
    SomeAttribute2 = c.someAttribute2,

    Parent = new Parent {
        Attribute1 = c.Parent.Attribute1,
        .......
    }
}
```

With the above statement, Entity Framework will only fetch the desired columns.

I don't want to make comparison or criticism between Hibernate for Java and Entity Framework for C#, absolutely.

I only have the need to fetch a subset of the columns that compose an entity with a `@ManyToOne` relationship, in order to optimize memory and bandwidth usage. Some columns from the child entity and some from the parent.

I just want to know if and how is it possible in Hibernate to achieve something like that. To populate `parent` attribute in the result set with an object of class `Parent` that is populated with only a subset of columns (the rest being null is no problem). I am using `ResultTransformer`s happily

Comment: What exactly does not work in the query above? Perhaps I missed something, but it looks valid to me. The only thing wrong with it is that `left join` is ignored since you are using `item.parent` in the `select` clause which translates to `inner join`. To avoid that you should use `select item.a1, p.p1 from Child item left join item.parent p`

Comment: @PredragMaric He wants to use nested projection aliases like this `parent.someParent1` as I think.

Comment: @v.ladynev You're probably right, didn't see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with it.

1. Hibernate doesn't allow to use nested aliases like `as parent.someName` in HQL. It produces a parsing error. But you can use nested aliases with `Criteria` using `Projections.property("parent.someName")`.
2. Hibernate doesn't have a result transformer to populate result objects using nested aliases.

You can use `Criteria` requests with a custom result transformer as described here

[How to transform a flat result set using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36361630/3405171)