# Hibernate Criteria Query to get only specific columns

Tags: hibernate, criteria, projection

I have two tables: ReportRows and DataRows

Table ReportRows:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "T_REPORT_CODE")
  private Report report;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "T_DATA_ROWS_ID")
  private DataRow dataRow;
```

additionally getters and setters;

Table DataRows:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

@Column(name = "VALUE_0")
    private String value0;

@Column(name = "VALUE_1")
    private String value1;

@Column(name = "VALUE_2")
    private String value2;

...

@Column(name = "VALUE_30")
    private String value30;
```

additionally getters and setters

Select from ReportRows and DataRows gets all columns from both tables when listing data. I need only a few columns from DataRows (i specify it).

Select which I want to get looks like this:

```
SELECT 
dataRows.value0,
dataRows.value1
from
t_report_rows this_
inner join
t_reports report_ on report_.id = this_.report_id
inner join
t_data_rows dataRows_ on dataRows_.id = this_t_data_rows_id
where report_.id = 1
```

It is only example which I wrote. The point is I need different columns each query. One time it will be value0, value1, second time it would be value0, value2.

When I do query I know which columns I need.
I create criteria like this (Columns is class from which I retrive names of columns):

```
public List<ReportRow> list(Criteria criteria, Long reportId) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("report.id", reportId));
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    for (Column col : columnList) {
        String columnName = getColumnId(col);
        projectionList.add(Projections.property(columnName));
        //I also tried like this:
        // projectionList.add(Projections.property(columnName), columnName);
        //or like this:
        //projectionList.add(Projections.property(columnName), getColumnId2(col));
        //also added this line with each of above:
        //criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ReportRow.class));
    }
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);

    return list(criteria);
}
```

Methods getColumnId and getColumnId2:

```
protected String getColumnId(Column col) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append("dataRow.value");
    b.append(col.getRowIndex());
    return b.toString();
  }

  protected String getColumnId2(Column col) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append("value");
    b.append(col.getRowIndex());
    return b.toString();
  }
```

I get error:
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: dataRow.value0

Is it even possible to do what I want? Get only specific columns from table dataRows based on Projection and table Column which store columns indexes?

Update 1:
I added custom transformer. Everything works fine. It was done to increase speed of sql. Now it is doing query with small amount of columns. It's really good. I turned on show sql in hibernate. After custom transformer it is doing to database for each row new query with:

```
where reportRowId = ?
```

Do you know why?

Custom Transformer transformTuple method looks like this for now:

```
@Override
  public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
    ReportRow row = new ReportRow();
    DataRow dataRow = new DataRow();
    row.setGridRow(dataRow);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < aliases.length; i++) {
      if ("id".equals(aliases[i])) {
        row.setId((Long) tuple[i]);
      } else if ("entityVersion".equals(aliases[i])) {
        row.setEntityVersion((Long) tuple[i]);
      } else if ("dataRowId".equals(aliases[i])) {
        dataRow.setId((Long) tuple[i]);
      } else if ("rowEntityVersion".equals(aliases[i])) {
        dataRow.setEntityVersion((Long) tuple[i]);
      } else if ("value0".equals(aliases[i])) {
        dataRow.setValue0((String) tuple[i]);
      } else if ("value1".equals(aliases[i])) {
        dataRow.setValue1((String) tuple[i]);
      }
    }

    return row;
  }
```

Comment: How is your Criteria created? Unrelated, but your getColumnId() method could be reduced to `return "dataRow.value" + col.getRowIndex();`, which would be much more readable and as, if not more efficient.

Comment: `Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getKind());` where getKind returns class. In this example: `ReportRow.class`

Comment: So, just as in your SQL query, you need a join: `criteria.createAlias("dataRow", "dataRow");`

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks. I have one more question. If I want return also in this query entity Report and columns value0, value1 what I have to do?

Comment: AFAIK, that is not possible. Either you return an entity, or columns, but not both.

Comment: Thanks. That was really helpful.

Comment: I have problem because when I setResultTransformer it returns objects with null variables. Example. getId() is null (I added `projectionList.add(Projections.property("id"));`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have problem because when I setResultTransformer it returns objects
>   with null variables. Example. getId() is null (I added
>   projectionList.add(Projections.property("id"));)

You need to specify an alias of the projection

```
projectionList.add(Projections.property("id").as("id"));
```

> Yes, it worked. Thanks. I have one more question. If I want return
>   also in this query entity Report and columns value0, value1 what I
>   have to do?

You can get a part of `Report` by specifying projections for columns of it. You need to get `ReportRows` as root and properties of `Report` and `DataRow` using nested projections.

For nested projections you can use a custom transformer

[How to transform a flat result set using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361256/how-to-transform-a-flat-result-set-using-hibernate)

Answer (score 3):

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DlrStatus.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId",userId)).add(Restrictions.eq("jobId",jobId))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("status", status)).setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(max).addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("mobile").as("mobile"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("Sender").as("sender"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("message").as("message"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("loggedAt").as("loggedAt"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("dlrTime").as("dlrTime"));
criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
List<DlrStatus> list = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to this code - especially for future readers to see what the problem was.