# Hibernate ignores fetchgraph

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitygraph

This is my entity:

```
public class PersonItem implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="col1")
    private String guid;

    @Column(name="col2")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="col3")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name="col4")
    private Date birthDate;
 //+getters and setters
}
```

This is how I get the list of persons:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("Select p from PersonItem p WHERE p.guid IN (:guids)");
EntityGraph<PersonItem> eg = em.createEntityGraph(PersonItem.class);
eg.addAttributeNodes("guid");
eg.addAttributeNodes("name");
eg.addAttributeNodes("surname");
query.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", eg);
query.setParameter("guids", guids);
List<PersonItem> list=query.getResultList();
em.close();
// And now I iterate result AFTER EM CLOSE
....iterate
```

If I understand fetch graph correcly it must load only those fields, which I specified. However, the field "birthDate" is also loaded. Besides I see that in hibernate sql query 4 columns are selected.

How to fix it? I use hibernate 5.1.0 as JPA provider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entity graphs are meant to control which relationships (e.g. one-to-one, one-to-many, etc.) are loaded lazily or eagerly.  They may not work for loading individual columns (it depends on the provider).

Hibernate has some support for this, but it is fairly difficult to get working, described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties).  However, they mention the following reticence towards this approach (which I whole-heartedly agree with):

> Please note that this is mostly a marketing feature; optimizing row
>   reads is much more important than optimization of column reads.

So I would not recommend going too far down this road until you've confirmed that this is indeed a bottleneck in your application (e.g. this kind of fetch tuning can be a symptom of premature optimization).

UPDATE:

As pointed out, JPA does leave it up to the provider as to whether or not simple columns (non-associations) are lazily fetched.

> The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider
>   runtime that data must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a 
>   hint to the persistence provider runtime that data should be fetched
>   lazily  when it is first accessed. The implementation is permitted to
>   eagerly fetch  data for which the LAZY strategy hint has been
>   specified. In particular, lazy fetching might only be available for
>   Basic mappings for which property-based access is used.

Starting with Hibernate 5, official support for bytecode enhancement was added and this may allow for lazy attribute fetching.

From the [latest Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-annotation) we have:

> 2.3.2
>
> fetch - FetchType (defaults to EAGER)
>
> Defines whether this attribute should be fetched eagerly or lazily.
>   JPA says that EAGER is a requirement to the provider (Hibernate) that
>   the value should be fetched when the owner is fetched, while LAZY is
>   merely a hint that the value be fetched when the attribute is
>   accessed. Hibernate ignores this setting for basic types unless you
>   are using bytecode enhancement.

And this next snippet that describes the advantages of bytecode enhancement.

> Lazy attribute loading
>
> Think of this as partial loading support. Essentially you can tell
>   Hibernate that only part(s) of an entity should be loaded upon
>   fetching from the database and when the other part(s) should be loaded
>   as well. Note that this is very much different from proxy-based idea
>   of lazy loading which is entity-centric where the entity’s state is
>   loaded at once as needed. With bytecode enhancement, individual
>   attributes or groups of attributes are loaded as needed.

Comment: The link you provided about hibernate 3.3 version. Maybe the things have changed since that time?

Comment: Could you comment this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/37053402/5057736 . There the man say that this code works with another jpa provider and this is according to JPA specs.

Comment: It may be supported if you use bytecode enhancement, also, my answer is specific to Hibernate.  I agree the JPA spec says that a provider can take either approach.  I'll update with relevant references from the latest docs.

Comment: This is wrong: `They are not intended (and do not work for) loading individual columns`. I've tested that approach in EclipseLink and it worked as expected. Only three columns were read from the DB.

Comment: I will admit that is wrong and will update my answer.  It may work but is not guaranteed to.  I've added references to the JPA spec explaining as much.