# JPA: how to tell CriteriaQuery to include lazy properties in returned entities?

Tags: jpa, properties, lazy-evaluation

JPA: how to tell CriteriaQuery to fetch lazy properties?
For example,

Student entity has description property that is declared lazy.

```
public class Student {

    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public String getDescription() {
           ...
    }
}
```

Retrieve all students eager fetching descriptions:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Student> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Student.class);
Root<Student> root = criteriaQuery.from(Student.class);
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
TypedQuery<Student> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Student> students = query.getResultList();
```

How to tell CriteriaQuerty to include student.description in query results?

For fetching lazy entities, I can use fetch

```
root.fetch("courses", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Comment: Use EntityGraph like the answer says. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049358/hibernate-load-entities-with-fields-defined-at-runtime/37053402#37053402

Answer (score 1):

You can use entity load graphs. This is fairly new and I think it's only supported in JPA2.1.

http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/

Comment: Entity graph in the article is a fetch plan for entity relations. Does it work for properties that are not entities, for example, clob? Thanks

Comment: EntityGraph is a fetch plan for ALL fields/properties! See the JPA spec!