# Hibernate Criteria: projection with joined entity

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to create a query with Criteria, but I don't succeed to map data from a joined entity.

With this Criteria query the id of the Order entity is override with the id of the ShippingCondition entity :

```
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Order.class, "o")
    .createAlias("o.shippingCondition", "sc", JoinType.INNER_JOIN)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("o.id"), "id")
        .add(Projections.property("o.orderNum"), "orderNum")
        .add(Projections.property("o.notes"), "notes")
        .add(Projections.property("sc.id"), "id"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("o.id", id))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Order.class));

return (Order) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

My entities :

```
@Table(name = "order", schema = "myschema")
public class Order {

    private Integer id;
    private String orderNum;
    private String notes;
    private ShippingCondition shippingCondition;
    ...
}

@Table(name = "shipping_condition", schema = "myschema")
public class ShippingCondition {

    private Integer id;
    private String shippingCondition;
    private Integer sorting;
    ...
}
```

I have tryed to replace `.add(Projections.property("sc.id"), "id")` by `.add(Projections.property("sc.id"), "shippingCondition.id")` but then I get a ClassCastException `(java.lang.ClassCastException: entity.Order cannot be cast to java.util.Map)`

Do you have any idea how I can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't support nested projections. You will need to create `DTO` for that. You can extend `DTO` from `Order` class and add methods to set fields of `ShippingCondition`.

```
class OrderDto extends Order {

  public OrderDto() {
      setShippingCondition(new ShippingCondition());
  }

  public void setShippingConditionId(Integer id) {
      getShippingCondition().setId(id);
  }

}
```

You can use a special nested transformer if you don't want to use `DTO`

[How to transform a flat result set using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361256/how-to-transform-a-flat-result-set-using-hibernate/36361630#36361630)

**Additional notes**

`JPA` doesn't support any transformers at all. And it is hard to implement such transformer by consistent way. For example, my transformer doesn't support child collections like `@OneToMany`, only single associations. Also, you can't use nested projections with HQL, because HQL doesn't support `parent.child` aliases.

Comment: It's working well, but it's strange that hibernate don't propose this solution. Is there a reason?

Comment: Do you have a slution for @OneToMany collection ? I don't want to use the getter in lazy mode, it's so ugly... I want to do only one query to get my data

Comment: @Nan You can try it yourself. Maybe it will work. And you can use `criteria.setFetchMode()` to fetch a collection.

Comment: Ok, but I just want to select some fields of my collection. I'm trying to do it with the transformer you gave me. I will push the solution when I will make it.

Comment: @Nan I think it is impossible. You can check entity graphs https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/

Comment: You're right it's impossible because Hibernate loader treats row by row. So the transformer is called on each row, but not on the full result.

Comment: @Nan Thank you. Probably transformer can accumulate rows to the list, if Hibernate passes the name of the association.